# How to represent first several Fibonacci numbers as a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, fibonacci-numbers

We know that first five fibonacci numbers are $\,0,1,1,2,3\,$. Now I want to include them in a set.

But according to Set theory a set cannot have duplicate elements. So, how can I write the set?

Should I write $S = \{0,1,2,3\}$ or should I write $S = \{0,1,1,2,3\}$?

And hence, what will be the number of elements in set of first five fibonacci numbers?

Actually I have got an exam question that says:

> $$B=\{x:x \;\text {is a Fibonacci number and}\ x^2 < 64\}$$
>
> Then what is the number of elements in Power set of $B$?

Here is where I need either to include the redundant $1$ or exclude it. Don't know what to do.

Comment: I would interpret a number to be Fibonacci if it is an element of the Fibonacci series. Then, as you point out, the set of Fibonacci numbers would be $\{0,1,2,3,5,\dots\}$. It would not contain duplicates as sets do not contain duplicates by definition.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Cleric. I have been trying to find the answer from yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to *exclude* it, so

$$B = \{0,1,2,3,5\}$$

is the set with $5$ elements, and consequently the number of elements in its power set is $2^5 = 32$.

You *may* write 
$$B = \{0,1,1,2,3,5\}$$
but it is still *the same set* with only $5$ elements - $0,1,2,3,\text{ and }5$.